# Is $ \sup \vert \vert A \vert - \vert B \vert \vert \geq \vert \sup \vert A \vert - \sup \vert B \vert \vert$?

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Is the title's statement true?

I was able to prove that $-\sup(\vert B \vert-\vert A \vert) \leq \sup \vert A \vert - \sup \vert B \vert \leq \sup(\vert A \vert - \vert B \vert)$

and of course that $\sup \vert \vert A \vert - \vert B \vert \vert = \max \{ \inf(\vert A \vert - \vert B \vert) , \sup(\vert A \vert - \vert B \vert)\}$.

and from that the statement is obvious, but I'm still not quite sure if I have not done a terrible mistake in my profs. ( it was very confusing :) )
so would like to know if it is really true.

Comment: It cannot be a strict inequality.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: typing mistake - switch every < or > i wrote with <= or >=

Comment: A good idea would be to post your proof to get feedback. You might have done a terrible mistake anyway.